# What is ensureIndex?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a nodejs student and creating some practice project. I'm recently saw this on my console, when I run `mongoose.set("debug", true)`.

What does it mean. Why it shows me an error like- duplicate key.

```
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ username: 1 }, 
 { unique: true, background: true })
Mongoose: posts.ensureIndex({ username: 1 }, 
 { unique: true, background: true })
```

How can I stop this to create like this and fix the error.

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: cms_demo1.poosts index: username_1 dup key: 
{ : null }
```

need help.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are using index on username and that should be unique.

Every time you do a write operation, the mongo ensures that the index is respected.

Now the issue of duplicate key, looks like you have one document where username value is null, now the next time you are passing any other document with username as null, it invalidates the unique constraint, which means there could be only one document with username as null.

If you want to use unique index and also wants to allow null avlue for username for multiple documents, you can use sparse option with index.

You can drop the index and recreate it with sparse option

```
db.users.dropIndex({username : 1});
db.users.ensureIndex({ username: 1 }, 
 { unique: true, background: true, sparse : true })
```

I am guessing you have given the index definition through mongoose, in that case just update the definition there with sparse option.

More on [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/)

Comment: actually i set the index by mistake. if i want to remove it now, how can i do that? i try dropIndex, but every time i run the program, it creates automatically. how i permanently stop that.

Comment: dropIndex is the way, If it's recreating it means you haven't removed the index signature from your program. You can try by dropping the collection too but I guess that is hope against hope. Better would be to find out from where db is getting that it has to recreate. ensureIndex is more or less an alias for createIndex.